# How do I center child div in parent and have it fixed to the top?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have a child div be centered horizontally (left/right) within the parent div and also fixed to the top of the parent div but I cant figure out how to do this in CSS :-( I can center it and I can fix it but anytime I try to combine the child div just gets fixed in its natural place (to the left).

EDIT: Child needs to be fixed to the top so when other children overflow they can be scrolled but it would stay in place.

Comment: Hi @donL Were any of the below answers helpful to you? If so, please select a "correct" answer *(by clicking the checkmark beside an answer)* to close the question, or provide an answer yourself and choose that as the correct answer. That would help us out. Otherwise, please add comments below one of the answers or edit your original question to add more detail so that additional answers can be provided. *Thanks!*

Answer (score 3):

Use flexbox - there's a reason why the major difference between Bootstrap3 and Bootstrap4 is switching from floats to flexbox!

Example:

```css
#parent{height:100px;background:red;}
#parent{display:flex;align-items:flex-start;justify-content:center;}

#child{background:yellow;}

XXX#child{flex-grow:1;text-align:center;} /* Uncomment if you want row to be full-width */
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">
     Here is some text
  </div>
</div>
```

References:

[Excellent flexbox cheatsheet](https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/#align-items)

[Excellenter *short* Video Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k32voqQhODc)

Answer (score 1):

```css
.parent{
  position: relative; // This is important
}

.child{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Comment: parent being relative didn't seem to make a difference for me in the end.

Comment: when you make an element `position: absolute;`, It will be positioned relative to the closest parent with a `position` defiled other than `static` (static is the default). So if you don't make your parent `relative` your child will be positioned relative to the document body.

Answer (score 0):

Try out following code

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

css is here

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: orangered;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
.child{
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: brown;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this was the solution:

```
.child{
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

thank you @Prithwee Das for the transform hint.